# Recruiter not responding after email exchange; should I be worried?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, email

I reached out to a recruiter that I had emailed earlier about her position for her company. I wasn't ready to move when she originally reached out to me.

The email exchange I had with her started out ok, but the didn't respond to my last email and I'm not sure why.

> Hi Susan,
>
> I was just reaching out as it's six months since we last spoke. I've gotten a lot of experience at my current company to build on what I've done in the past.  And I'd like to know if there are any opportunities we could explore at Company X that I might be a good fit for?
>
> Thank you,
> Tom

---

> Hi Tom,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to me! Yes, we do have roles at Company X open - do you have time to connect this week to chat about them?
>
> Best,
> Susan

---

> Hi Susan,
>
> Cool! That's so good to hear. Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Yes, I do have some time to chat this week. This week is a little lite because a lot of folks are out on vacation. If you suggest a time that works for you, I will do my best to accommodate that. I don't think there will be any problems there.
>
> Thank you,
> Tom

---

I think she might not be responding because recruiters don't like it when you shift the responsibility on them to find a time to talk. Something I don't usually do, but my week this week was light because it's near Christmas. So I thought I could just ask her for the best time for her.

Also I thought my response may have been to informal. Maybe it was too unprofessional for her to respond to?

The email exchange happened on Monday, early in the day. And she expressed a wish to talk sometime this week.

Maybe I'm just being too impatient? Or the way I handled it is putting her off. I'd like some opinions on that. I'd like to use this as a learning experience, because I really want to work at this company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I thought my response may have been to informal. Maybe it was too unprofessional for her to respond to?

Based on the text you quoted your response didn't seem unprofessional at all. On the contrary, you were quite polite and professional.

> Maybe I'm just being too impatient?

Yes, it's been less than 3 days since the exchange, I think it's a bit earlier to worry or think something went wrong.

Comment: OK that's great. Thank you! That's what I was hoping to find out. :-)

Comment: @user99201 glad I could help. If any, you could have used something else instead of "Cool!", but even so, using it doesn't make you rude or unprofessional. I'd give it a couple of days and she will surely reply.

Comment: OK, that's good! I was wondering about that too. I thought maybe responding with "cool" may put someone off as unprofessional. I feel better after this exchange, I will cool my jets and wait to hear back from her.

Comment: Thank you, again!

Comment: Hmm... she's still not responding. Reason I'm concerned is that she said she wanted to speak THIS week and now it's Friday. Do I want to follow up, or would that only hurt my cause?

Comment: @user99201 Yeah if she said this week then following up does not seem a bad idea. I also suggest you keep your options open and look for job elsewhere in case this recruiter doesn't reply at all or doesn't find you something

Comment: Cool, thanks! I just did and I will keep my fingers crossed. I will also keep my options open so that all my eggs aren't in one basket.

Comment: She just got back to me. Weeks later! I already made it through one interview. They need like 8 interviews before they let you in.

 But now I have another offer on the table and I'll probably have to take that before I go through their interview process. C'est la vie!